# Rails 4 RSpec warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In trying to run RSpec on Rails 4, I immediately get a warning:

```
you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead
```

that comes up in the backtrace assigned to the line

```
require 'rspec/rails'
```

in `spec_helper.rb`  If I add this before it

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
```

the warning goes away. Is this a fix? Should I also remove the line

```
require 'rspec/autorun'
```

that follows? Alternatively, the problem goes away without changing the `spec_helper.rb` file if I add

```
gem 'minitest'
```

to the gemfile

It will do this with a single spec file that only contains

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

We're running Rails 4.1.0.beta.

Comment: I just generated a new Rails `4.0.0.rc1` app, installed RSpec, and ran the specs, but couldn't reproduce this.  Are you still on Rails 4 beta?

Comment: We're running 4.1.0.beta

Comment: Given Rails 4.0.0 isn't even out yet, I imagine 4.1.0 is *very* in flux and strangeness is to expected. If you think it's a bug, file it as a bug.

Comment: Sorry to go slightly off topic here, I'm also getting the same warning, but the rails 4.1.0.beta seems to be installed when following the instructions in the generated gemfile if you use rails 4.0.0.rc1 `# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'` so @sevenseacat, are you saying that actually, we should stick with rc1 due to instability?

Comment: @Promethean_Sin If you use the Github repository for edge rails, yes you will get 4.1.0 beta. I wouldn't recommend anyone using edge Rails unless they are very confident in diagnosing and fixing their own issues, as outlined here. Stick to named versions if you're just building normal apps.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, I think I must have misread the instructions in the gemfile as you are using edge rails, instead use, rather than if you want to use edge rails, use this

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this:
https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/pull/772

If you use 'shoulda' or 'shoulda-matchers' in your Gemfile, please add 'require: false' to them.

Answer (score 0):

This is still a bug for Rspec 3.0.0 in Rails 4.1.1. It is important to put `gem 'minitest'` before `gem 'rspec-rails'` in the Gemfile, otherwise it won't work. If you're using flexmock, minitest needs to go before that too.